# CSS Why overline doesn't change color and style on hover?

Tags: html, css, colors, hover

im trying to do links that when you :hover appears an overline with a diferent color than the text, here's the code it seems to be correct for me but doesn't work and i dont know why :S

```
.subboto a:hover {
   text-decoration: overline;
   text-decoration-color: #f7a319;
   text-decoration-style: dashed;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ytq235an/)

Comment: Declare a class to text-decoration-color. An add this to every `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-decoration-color` is only supported in Firefox and Safari. Take a look at the docs here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color

If you want to do this you could do it like this

```
.subboto a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.subboto a:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px dashed #f7a319;
    content: ' ';
}
```

Take a look at the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ytq235an/6/

Comment: Works for me on IE 11 - there's a section on browser support here (10 day old article) https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration/

Comment: @wunth not for `text-decoration-color`. Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-color/ -- It says it can be turned on with a flag in Chrome but most users are going to do that.

Comment: Ah yes - apologies. Somewhere along the line I absolutely lost sight of the actual question

Comment: @wunth no problem. You got me to come back and provide a work-around :p

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be only supported by Firefox.
[w3schools text-decoration-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-style.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the overline to show up when you hover over the div

```
.subboto:hover {
    text-decoration: overline;
    text-decoration-color: #f7a319;
    text-decoration-style: dashed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration-color` is only supported in Firefox ([check reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp))

---

**Posible solution to your problem:**

```
.subboto a:hover {
    border-top: 1px dashed #f7a319;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ferrrmolina/ytq235an/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought me to this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp

I clicked the "try it yourself" button but the underline wasn't red as it should be. The text states that it is not supported in any of the major browsers, but firefox does have a custom option.

Unless you're fine with it only working on firefox, you're going to have to go about it a different way

REFER TO THIS IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbTXE.png